# ubuntu vm cannot find new network cards

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, virtualbox-networking

After copying the virtual hard disk of a vm I made to a new machine, ubuntu no longer recognises the network cards and spews out errors like:

`failed to bring up eth0 ..... no such device`

I'm guessing that this is to do with the change in MAC address (since the *type* of network card has remained the same). Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: `ifconfig` only shows the loopback interface, no others.

EDIT 2: `ip addr` shows they've moved to eth2 and eth3???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the contents of the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and rebooting did the trick :)